# Serialize nested attributes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

So I have models like this:

- `folder`, `up_file` has 1 `chat_room`
- `chat_room` belongs to `crmable` with polymorphic: true (so 1 `chat_room` may belongs to `folder` or 1 `up_file`)
- `chat_room` has many `comments`
- `comment` belongs to `chat_room` and `user` (who posted the comment)

I've defined all relationship like this:

```
class Folder < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :chat_room, as: :crmable, dependent: :destroy
end

class UpFile < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :chat_room, as: :crmable, dependent: :destroy
end

class ChatRoom < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :crmable, polymorphic: true

    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :chat_room
    belongs_to :user
end
```

This setup worked fine with my web app. However, I'm writing API for this app, and I can't get that nested associations serialized with this gem

```
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers
```

I've follow their tutorial [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/1127) but my associations not rendered.

```
class FolderSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

    attributes :id, :name, :ancestry, :creator_name #... my other attributes

    has_one :chat_room, include: [ :id, comments: :user ]
    # ^ I tried to serialize folder's chat_room with all it comments, along with these comments' users.
end
```

All I got is this - `chat_room` association not serialized?

[image]